# How can I ignore SSL/TLS validation using the Fetch API?

Tags: node.js, ssl, electron, fetch

I'm using the [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) API to download files from within an Electron render process. The server provides a self-signed certificate.

Electron throws the following exception:

[image: electron exception]

I do not want to turn of SSL/TLS entirely. Using `process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;` or setting the environment variable work, but this is completely insecure.

This is currently what I'm doing to fetch from the URL.

```
const requestInit: RequestInit = {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "GET"
    };
const response = await fetch(url, requestInit);
```

Comment: TBH, ignoring certificate validation error is "mostly" turning TLS entirely down. Ok, not true technically as you still have confidentiality through the encryption, but if you encrypt data and send it to a party you did not authenticate, then it means you are probably sending it to "anyone", in which case the fact that it is encrypted kind of stop providing any value. Authentication and confidentially are separate properties, but there is an assumption that confidentiality is more important and comes first when I think it should be the opposite. Of course authentication is a bigger problem...

Comment: Instead: if you can't change the server to make it stop sending a self signed certificate, and if this certificate is bound to persist for a long time, you should instead add that specific certificate as fully trusted in the trust store used by your application. In that way you remain 100% in TLS land with both confidentiality and authentication. Of course, if the certificate changes "often",  then it is more difficult.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMevzek. Unfortunately I cannot change the certificate being used on the server, I can only install the certificate as a Trusted Root Certificate Authority. Even after doing this, this error is still presented. Is it possible that an intermediary certificate is required for validation?

Comment: If it is a self signed certificate, by definition there can not be any intermediary certificate.

Comment: There’s no way specifically for Fetch API calls that you can make TLS validation be ignored. The browser transparently handles TLS negotiation, regardless of how you make the call. Browsers don’t allow web applications to selectively ignore TLS validation when making requests — regardless of how the requests are made (whether it’s with the Fetch API, or XHR, or using a Ajax method from a particular JavaScript library, or whatever).

Answer (score -5):

You'll find that SSL/TLS is the protocol required to make a request to the URL you pass. If it is an 'https://' url, then try removing the s to make an 'http://' request.  If the service does not support an SSL/TLS free option, then you'll have to support their choice to require SSL/TLS.

Comment: The OP said: "I do not want to turn of SSL/TLS entirely." so switching to HTTP from HTTPS defeats completely that goal...

Comment: Right... Then I guess it would be making an exception for their self-signed certificate

Comment: For reference, I'm leaving this up as the answer - You either use HTTPS, or HTTP. There is no try. Selectively taking some of HTTPS is not an option. The self-signed certificate means that there is no trusted certificate authority, and the origin of the underpinning of the security is untrusted. It's like renting a post office box, but you're not allowed to lock it, and Steve gets your mail for you.